Functional equation involving periodic functions and derivative
Let $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$, and $w > 0$ be a real number. Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be an even differentiable function, and periodic of period $w$. Show that if $f$ satisfies
$$f(x) + [f'(x)]^2=\dfrac{1}{f\left(x+(2n+1)\dfrac w4\right)}$$
for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then $\frac{w}{4}$ is also a period of $f$.
How can I approach this problem? I think the derivative squared in the equation is what made it harder we don’t really have information about it rather then just the derivative being odd because it’s derived from an even function!

Hi, welcome to MSE! What have you tried? Can you at least see how to show that $w/2$ is a period for example? I don't have a clue myself for $w/4$ at the moment but $w/2$ is pretty manageable.

Well i did not try w/2 because it’s not mentioned in the problem but for w/4 i tried making other equations trying to make some kind of equation where 2 terms will cancel out at least and that didn’t work too well for me

Do you have too many brackets ? hmm

Not enough >:((

@Alilou Is my edit not better ( I removed brackets ) or is it not equivalent now ?
I interpreted it as such. You can undo the edit or let me know if it is wrong. Im not sure what you meant

Yes ,it is better thank you man (i gotta learn LaTeX)

I considered solving for $f(0) = 0$ and  $f(x) f'(x)^2 + f(x)^2 = 1 $ and I found one solution :  $x^2 = (\frac{2}{3} f(x)^{3/2} 2F1(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{4}, \frac{7}{4}, f(x)^2))^2$ where $2F1$ means a hypergeometric function.

You talk about $f(x)$ being an even function. Can you tell us why ?

In fact I got the general $x + (2 c^{3/2} Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, 3/4, 7/4, c^2])/3 == (2 f[x]^{3/2} Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, 3/4, 7/4, f[x]^2])/3 $ where $c = f(0)$.

f(x) is even is given in the exercise
